# How to pass variable into function inside html tag function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating an HTML web app and getting all data from API calls. I have set data into an array and display them using the map function in javascript.

**My data set like below;**

```
contDet = [
    {
      idappcontent: "Review1_Ques_01",
      content:
        '<img src="#FOLDERPATH#logo.png" style="width:600px;height: 150px">',
    },
    {
      idappcontent: "Review1_Ques_02",
      content:
        '<div style="color:black;font-size:1.3em;text-align:center;"><p>Your Opinion Is Important To Us</p></div><div style="color: black; text-align: justify;font-size: 1em;line-height: 21px;margin-left: 3%;margin-right: 3%;"><p>Please take a moment to share with us your thoughts on your visit today.</p></div>',
    },
    {
      idappcontent: "Review1_Ques_03",
      content: '<ul data-role="listview" id="Review1_Ques_04">',
    },
    {
      idappcontent: "Review1_Ques_06",
      content:
        '<a style="float: left;">< </a><a style="<a id="review1btn1" data-role="button" class="linkbtnPrevious"  onclick="R1goPrevious()"><B>PREVIOUS</B></a><a style="float: right;">> </a> <a id="review1btn" data-role="button"  class="linkbtnNext"  onclick="goNext()"><B>NEXT</B></a>',
    },
  ];
  contImg = [
    { idclient: "11", idlocation: "25", ImageName: "highlightedStar.png" },
    { idclient: "11", idlocation: "25", ImageName: "star.png" },
  ];
  surQue = [
    { idsurveyquestion: "22", question: "Taste of the food?" },
    { idsurveyquestion: "23", question: "Quality of the food?" },
    { idsurveyquestion: "24", question: "Speed Of delivery?" },
    { idsurveyquestion: "25", question: "The accuracy of the order?" },
    { idsurveyquestion: "26", question: "How is our service?" },
  ];
```

My question is I have display images using the map function and there is a function for onclick. Now I need to pass item data into the on-click function.

**This is what I tried:**

**1.Js file**

```
var starImgpath, highlightedStarImgpath;
function getData() {
  contDet = [
    {
      idappcontent: "Review1_Ques_01",
      content:
        '<img src="#FOLDERPATH#logo.png" style="width:600px;height: 150px">',
    },
    {
      idappcontent: "Review1_Ques_02",
      content:
        '<div style="color:black;font-size:1.3em;text-align:center;"><p>Your Opinion Is Important To Us</p></div><div style="color: black; text-align: justify;font-size: 1em;line-height: 21px;margin-left: 3%;margin-right: 3%;"><p>Please take a moment to share with us your thoughts on your visit today.</p></div>',
    },
    {
      idappcontent: "Review1_Ques_03",
      content: '<ul data-role="listview" id="Review1_Ques_04">',
    },
    {
      idappcontent: "Review1_Ques_06",
      content:
        '<a style="float: left;">< </a><a style="<a id="review1btn1" data-role="button" class="linkbtnPrevious"  onclick="R1goPrevious()"><B>PREVIOUS</B></a><a style="float: right;">> </a> <a id="review1btn" data-role="button"  class="linkbtnNext"  onclick="goNext()"><B>NEXT</B></a>',
    },
  ];
  contImg = [
    { idclient: "11", idlocation: "25", ImageName: "highlightedStar.png" },
    { idclient: "11", idlocation: "25", ImageName: "star.png" },
  ];
  surQue = [
    { idsurveyquestion: "22", question: "Taste of the food?" },
    { idsurveyquestion: "23", question: "Quality of the food?" },
    { idsurveyquestion: "24", question: "Speed Of delivery?" },
    { idsurveyquestion: "25", question: "The accuracy of the order?" },
    { idsurveyquestion: "26", question: "How is our service?" },
  ];

  //set content
  document.getElementById("Review1_Ques_01").innerHTML = contDet[0].content;
  document.getElementById("Review1_Ques_02").innerHTML = contDet[1].content;
  document.getElementById("Review1_Ques_03").innerHTML = contDet[2].content;
  document.getElementById("Review1_Ques_06").innerHTML = contDet[3].content;

  //set star image path
  //geting star img
  var starImg = contImg.filter(function (item) {
    return item.ImageName.includes("star");
  });
  starImgpath =
    "./images/" +
    starImg[0].idclient +
    "/" +
    starImg[0].idlocation +
    "/" +
    starImg[0].ImageName;

  //geting highlightedStar img
  var highlightedStarImg = contImg.filter(function (item) {
    return item.ImageName.includes("star");
  });
  highlightedStarImgpath =
    "./images/" +
    highlightedStarImg[0].idclient +
    "/" +
    highlightedStarImg[0].idlocation +
    "/" +
    highlightedStarImg[0].ImageName;

  document.getElementById("Que_list").innerHTML = surQue
    .map(
      (item) =>
        `<div>
        <p class="ques">${item.question}</P>
      <div class="str">
            <img  onClick="rate()"  class="star" id=1${item.idsurveyquestion} src=${starImgpath} />
            <img  onClick="rate()"  class="star" id=2${item.idsurveyquestion}} src=${starImgpath} />
            <img  onClick="rate()"  class="star" id=3${item.idsurveyquestion}} src=${starImgpath} />
            <img  onClick="rate()"  class="star" id=4${item.idsurveyquestion}} src=${starImgpath} />
            <img  onClick="rate()"  class="star" id=5${item.idsurveyquestion}} src=${starImgpath} />
        </div>
    </div>`
    )
    .join("");
}

function rate(item) {
  console.log("working");
  const { id } = event.target;
  console.log(id);

  for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    if (parseInt(i + item.idsurveyquestion) <= parseInt(id)) {
      document
        .getElementById(parseInt(i + item.idsurveyquestion))
        .setAttribute("src", highlightedStarImgpath);
    } else {
      document
        .getElementById(parseInt(i + item.idsurveyquestion))
        .setAttribute("src", starImgpath);
    }
  }
}
```

How Can I pass item into onClick="rate()" this function?

Comment: Try you used concatenation?

Comment: I tried it with onClick="rate(${item})". But it gives me an error. "Unexpected identifier"

Answer (score 0):

```js
surQue.map(
      (item) =>
      {
        // Create the image element dynamically in the map function
        var imageElement = document.createElement('img');
        imageElement.addEventListener('click', function(){
          rate(item);
        });

        // Once created the image element, you can append it to an  
        // existing div or any other element
        var listElement = document.getElementById('Que_list');
        listElement.innerHTML += imageElement;
      }
    );
```